# program gets stuck after delete[] char* in c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

so I'm writing an object-oriented code in c++ for a project and I get a problem in the destructor function when deleting a char* field of a class String I'm creating (I need to use char* and can't replace it with std::string for this assignment). the problem occurs when I'm trying to initialize a new object.
this is the String Class code:

```
// default C'tor
String::String() {
    str = new char('\0');
}

/// <summary>
/// C'tor which gets a string and copies it to the objects string  while removing unnecessary whitespaces
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">: string to copy</param>
String::String(char* str) {
    this->str = new char('\0');
    int i = 0;
    str = strtok(str, " \t");
    while (str) {
        if (i != 0)
            strcat(this->str, " ");
        strcat(this->str, str);
        str = strtok(NULL, " \t");
        i++;
    }
}

// Copy C'tor
String::String(const String& str_obj) {
    str = new char;
    *str = *(str_obj.str);
}

// D'tor
String::~String() {
    delete[] str; // after debugging i found the after this specific line the program stops (but 
                  // doesn't crash or exits just doesn't go further in the code)
    str = NULL;
}

// overriding the assignment operator
String& String::operator=(const String& str_obj) {
    delete[] str;
    str = new char[strlen(str_obj.str) + 1];
    memset(str, '-',strlen(str_obj.str));
    strcpy(this->str, str_obj.str);
    return *this;
}
```

This is how I try to create the new object:

```
// this is part of my main file
#include "String.h"

cout << "Please enter clients' id: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, input);
temp_str = new char[input.length() + 1];
strcpy(temp_str, input.c_str());
id = String(temp_str); // after this line the program stops continuing
delete[] temp_str;
cout << endl;
```

and I don't know why this is happening, hope someone can help me fix it

Comment: `str = new char; *str = *(str_obj.str);` this is not doing what you think it is. `this->str = new char('\0'); str = strtok(str, " \t");` this is almost definitely writing out of bounds. You need to review how memory allocation should work. If possible, I'd suggest you avoid the pointers altogether.

Comment: `this->str = new char('\0');`  also `str = new char;` and `str = new char('\0');` you are allocating space for only a null terminator and nothing more. This won't be a useful string class if it can only contain an empty string.

Comment: `str = new char;` and `delete[] str;` are mismatched.

Comment: Your class seems to be missing a `length` member variable.  If you had that, then you don't need those excessive calls to `strlen`  Every call to `strlen` has to start from the beginning of the string and count the number of characters until a null-terminator is reached.  Doing that over and over again for no reason will slow the code down excessively.

Answer (score -3):

It runs ok to me after I added the parts necessary for compilation. I tested in codeblocks 17.12 with MinGW 7.4. Please try the following code. I would like to what will be the outcome. I only removed the `cin.ignor()`, it erased the first character in the input string.

```
#ifndef Class_String__
#define Class_String__
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// Class_String__
struct String
{
     char *str;
     String();
     String(char* str);
     String(const String& str_obj);
     ~String();
     String& operator=(const String& str_obj);
};
     String::String() {
        str = new char('\0');
     }
/// <summary>
/// <param name="str">: string to copy</param>
  String::String(char* str) {
     this->str = new char ('\0');
     int i = 0;
     str = strtok(str, " \t");
     while (str != NULL) {
         if (i != 0) strcat(this->str, " ");
         strcat(this->str, str);
         str = strtok(NULL, " \t");
         i++;
     }
}
// Copy C'tor
String::String(const String& str_obj) {
    str = new char;
    *str = *(str_obj.str);
}
// D'tor
String::~String() {
    delete[] str;
    str = NULL;
}
//overriding the assignment operator
String& String::operator=(const String& str_obj) {
    delete[] str;
    str = new char[strlen(str_obj.str) + 1];
    memset(str, '-',strlen(str_obj.str));
    strcpy(this->str, str_obj.str);
    return *this;
}
#endif
//
int main()
{
    std::string input;
    String id;
    char *temp_str;
    cout << "Please enter clients' id: ";
    //cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, input);
    temp_str = new char[input.length() + 1];
    strcpy(temp_str, input.c_str());
    id = String(temp_str); // after this line the program stops continuing
    delete[] temp_str;
    cout << id.str << endl;
 }
```

The result from this shit tested in MSYS2 with MinGW 10.x:

```
 ytlu@ytlu-PC MINGW32 /d/ytlu/working/cpptest
 $ g++ shit.cpp -o a.exe
 
 ytlu@ytlu-PC MINGW32 /d/ytlu/working/cpptest
 $ ./a.exe
 Please enter clients' id:   This    is   a  test.
 This is a test.
```

Comment: "it runs ok to [you]" because there's a bunch of undefined behavior here. Just saying "it runs find for me" isn't really useful for the OP (and doesn't answer the question besides).

Comment: Even if this happened to work in the setup your using, it's still undefined behaviour to allocate memory with regular `new` (as opposed to `new[]`) then deallocate it with `delete[]` (as opposed to regular `delete`). You also haven't addressed the write out of bounds, which is also undefined behaviour.

Comment: @scohe001  The above code runs ok to me. Of course, I added parts to make it compiled, and that are all common stuffs. What else I should do to investigate this. Teach me after you example the above code.

Comment: @ArthurTacca You may try in other environment, and teach me how it is working in my set up. Not only give a negative judgement before you try it.

Comment: `this->str = new char ('\0'); str = strtok(str, " \t");` writes out of bounds of allocated memory. `*str = *(str_obj.str);` is not how you copy a string and is almost definitely not what OP wants. `delete [] str;` will attempt to delete a char array, when you've only allocated a single character. There's probably more I'm not catching on just a quick glance through.

Comment: @scohe001 The assignment operator is not activated yet. I am not working on it.

Comment: None of what I mentioned was in the assignment operator.

Comment: @scohe001  str = strtok(str, " \t"); works alright. I am sure of this.

Comment: str = strtok(str, " \t"); works alright. I am sure of this, and had some experience with it, What surprise me is ' str = new char ("/0") ;' worked in mingw 7.4.

Comment: @ytlu Judging the *correctness* of any code, and especially C/C++ code by it not crashing when run is foolish in the extreme. Get a free static analyzer like cppcheck or pvs-studio (free for use on open source stuff) and see what it tells you about this code :)

Comment: @UnslanderMonica What you proposed is far beyond my capacity. Please do that and let me know your result. and I am not capable of judging the wrongness of a code, if it is runing ok.

Comment: The new operator accepted inititializer list, therefore 'char *str = new char ("\0");' is legal. It created an char array of length 1, and gives value '\0'. Then in the constructor 'Sting::String(char *)', the strings are copied into str, make the length become expandable, just like std::string. I found this expansion works under MinGW 7.4 and 10.x. This is about the end of my kits. You big guy please pronouce your reasons what I should make corrections, not some general programming guids, I am not the OP, certainly this is not the way I write my code.

Comment: I didn't find the evidence that the program clashed in the destructor, and I would like to present it to the OP for him to test. Hope this small intention is OK for you. And if you want make judgement, please do your test run first.

Comment: @ytlu If you drive through a red light, and you don't get into trouble, did that mean it "worked ok for you"? Would you advise others to do the same? Like driving, C++ has rules. Even if you don't follow them, you might get lucky and not crash, but you're still doing the wrong thing. If you don't know the rules of C++ then you shouldn't post an answer here, even if you find a program that didn't crash for you – it's unfair on novices that might read it looking for advice, and be tempted to copy your mistakes.

Comment: @ArthurTacca It's not my mistake, I simply cannot find his mistake. Can you? Show me. I didn't advice him, I only added some trivial parts, and found that his code works alright.

Comment: Then I go to check the manual, and found the documents that support his writing. And then, a group of experts keep saying I was wrong. But I didn't do anything yet.

Comment: The only two things I did: 1. I remark the line cin.ignore(); this is rather irrelavent; 2. I added std::cout << id.str << std::endl; the argument id.str was missed in his original version. I didn't mention it thnking it was an typo. Now, I think he may be missed the subject of stream out, which casue the exexution ended without print out anything.  >>>>I didn't yet do any contribution to the problem <<<<

Comment: Of course, there maybe havfe some other problems in the copy constructor and assign operator., but they had not been activated and irrelavant to the post problem. I am not working on these, but simply focus on the problem he posted.